# Delete and join, then set a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables that I want to update in the same Mysql query, the first one is named `tags` and the second one is named `links`.

The tags table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`name` text,
`title` text,
`use_number` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And the links table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_pos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Given a `links.entry_id`, I want to delete all associated rows in the `links` table and then, joining `links.tag_id` and `tags.id`, decrease the associated `tags.use_number` by 1.

I tried to make a query that would do that but it isn't valid apparently.

```
DELETE FROM links INNER JOIN tags ON links.tag_id = tags.id AND entry_id = ? SET tags.use_number = tags.use_number - 1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set is the part of an update command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't valid syntax for a DELETE statement.

You can't update a table in your DELETE query.

What you can do is create a `trigger before delete` that will update your tags table, by decreasing the associated tags.use_number by 1 `WHERE tags.id = OLD.tag_id`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER decrease_tags_use_number BEFORE DELETE ON links
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE tags SET use_number = use_number - 1 WHERE id = OLD.tag_id;
  END;
```